# Why is this positioning, displaying not working?

Tags: html, css

```
<article id="l1">
    <img class="active_pic" id="a1" src="img/load.gif"/>
</article>
<article id="l2">
    <img class="active_pic" id="a2" src="img/load.gif"/>
</article>
<article id="l3">
    <img class="active_pic" id="a3" src="img/load.gif"/>
</article>
```

So this is the HTML I want the `<article>`'s to be side by side, touching each other.
This is what I made in CSS:

```
article{
   height:90%;
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   border:0;
   text-align:left;
   display:inline-block;
}
```

Problems, they don't touch each other, they stay in line, only if I change to display:inline, but I want display:inline-block, but when I do so it takes up 100% width instead of width the picture it contains.

I know this is a lame question, but I tried everything I knew.

EDIT: Here is a link of what I'm trying to do:

http://kozkincsprogram.hu/clooud/galery.html

when it loads pick the left drawing, which is 'colorful' to make my problem appear

Comment: `float: left` should achieve what you're after.

Comment: What are the pixel dimensions for load.gif?

Comment: its just for loading, when the page is loaded i change the src and those images' dimensions vary

Comment: For the article element, the height is 90%.  Is there a height for the containing block?

Comment: So you want three images to fit within the width of the page, so they need to auto-scale by width somehow...

Comment: nope! I want them to be in one line, the pictures don't fit there they wont get showed, overflow:hidden on the parent of <article>s, I just want them who fit there to be on one line.. and yes the parent element's height is 97%

Comment: I want to make a gallery, where you see as many pictures as you can when the galery's height is 97% of your screen.Pictures are side by side, there is a left and a right arrow, when you click the right arrow you make the actual first displaying picture become hidden (display:none) so your second becomes first and so on. So I need an array of pictures which height is defined by percentage and the width is auto according to the actual picture. THey touch each other.

Answer (score 0):

try

http://jsfiddle.net/PHhdm/

```
article{
   height:90%;
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   border:0;
   text-align:left;
float:left;
}
article > img{
    border:1px solid red;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
   display:inline-block;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this using floats instead?

```
article{
   height:90%;
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   border:0;
   text-align:left;
   float:left;
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

Check out the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WEfPj/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using floats

`article {
 float: left;
 width: //add the width here i.e. 100px; 20%?
}`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in other answers, you're likely looking for `float: left` on your `article` elements, but you'll probably also want to set `display: block` on your images to remove the extra whitespace that exists between the `article` and `img` elements.

```
article {
    height:90%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
    text-align:left;
    float: left;
}

article > img { display: block; }
```

Comment: okay now the pictures touch, but float left solved nothing, <article> still takes up 100% width!

Comment: Can you provide a demo/fiddle of the issue you're having? The link you originally provided is too broad.

Answer (score 0):

Why would they take up less than the full width of the page if you haven't told them how much space they're entitled to?

If you want 3 elements side by side, go with a width of around 30% and use margins to even them out.

Bottom line is you need a `width`.

You might also find `CSS3`'s `calc()` quite useful to. `min-width` & `max-width` could also be useful here.